# How to remove a permission to a SPPrincipal on a Item (programmatically)

Tags: development, security, profiling

I'm trying to work with privileges on elements of a list. I want the item to mantain the same privileges for all SPPrincipal I don't modify.

This is the code

```
    public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType) 
     { 
         if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
         { 
             item.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true); 
          } 

    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj); 
    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType); 
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition); 

    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment); 
}
```

This code (proposed to me by Alexander), destroys all the permissions and add the permission specified as parameter..

To mantain the past privileges I must set

```
item.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);
```

which mantains the old privileges.

I tried to make a RemoveAll on the roleAssignment before the add of the new one, but it mantains also the old privileges, like RemoveAll didn't to anything!

This is the code:

```
 public static void AddPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
    {
        if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);
        }

        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
        roleAssignment.Update();

        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    }
```

My code (simplyfied):

```
  [WebMethod]
    public ResponseObject InsertInAllReplyers(string username)
    {
        ResponseObject SPResultStatus = new ResponseObject();
        try
        {

                SPUserToken myToken = TokenManager.GetToken(username);
                //ATTENZIONE!! SOLO PER LA MACCHINA LOCALE DIEGO VA MANTENUTO LO SPAZIO!!!
                string fullsite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/sites/Reply Corp";
                //ATTENZIONE!! SOLO PER LA MACCHINA LOCALE DIEGO VA MANTENUTO LO SPAZIO!!!
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(fullsite, myToken))
                {
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    using (SPWeb currentWeb = site.OpenWeb("All Replyers"))
                    {

                        currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList targetList = currentWeb.Lists["Contenuti"];
                        SPListItem listItem = targetList.AddItem();
                        listItem["Title"] = "Prova :)";
                        listItem["tt_contentid"] = "TT_ID252";
                        listItem["Tag"] = "Tag2";
                        listItem.Update();

                        var allreplyers = currentWeb.Groups["All Replyers"];
                        AssignPermissionsToItem(listItem, (SPPrincipal)allreplyers, SPRoleType.Reader);
                        AssignPermissionsToItem(listItem, (SPPrincipal)currentWeb.AllUsers[username], SPRoleType.Contributor);

                        SPResultStatus.SPResultStatus = ResponseObjectSPResultStatus.SUCCESS;
                        SPResultStatus.SPResultUrl = listItem.Url;
                        SPResultStatus.SPResultId = listItem.ID.ToString();
                        SPResultStatus.SPResultType = ResponseObjectSPResultType.LIST;

                        }

                }
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            return new ResponseObject() { SPResultStatus = ResponseObjectSPResultStatus.FAILURE, Message = exx.Message, Stacktrace = exx.StackTrace, ExceptionType = exx.GetType().ToString() };
        }
        return SPResultStatus;
    }

    public static void AssignPermissionsToItem(SPListItem item, SPPrincipal obj, SPRoleType roleType)
    {
        if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            item.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
        }
        item.RoleAssignments.Remove(obj); 
        item.SystemUpdate(); 

        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(obj);
        SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = item.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);

        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    }
```

Comment: I've posted an answer but if it doesn't help could you post the code of your RemoveAll method?

Comment: Just added the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do an update to your list item before adding the role again.

```
oListItem.RoleAssignments.Remove(principal);
oListItem.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: It tolds me i cannot do that operation with my privilege even if I'm in a Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges part...

Comment: Odd - what if you use just an update intead of a system update? Can you post the code leading up to that point? Specifically how you get your item object? Also for the record, any time I've worked with permissions I've only ever done RoleAssignments.Remove() and not RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll(). I'm not sure what route is necessarily better, that is just what has worked for me.

Comment: Looking at the example I have in front of me (code someone I know wrote) they also do an Update() right after BreakRoleInheritance() - Not sure if this is bad programming or a requirement. Worth trying though.